# JAXB - injecting code into a simpleType

Tags: jaxb, maven-3, xjc

I am trying to find out how to inject a code into a xsd simpleType that is an ennumeration.

My XSD is just like below inside commons.xsd

```
<xsd:simpleType name="tPessoa">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Enumeracao que descreve se e uma pessoa fisica ou
            juridica
            Valores possiveis:
            - pf: para PESSOA FiSICA;
            - pj: para PESSOA
            JURiDICA.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="pf" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="pj" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

My binding is just like below

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../src/main/resources/commons.xsd"
    node="//xsd:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="my.canonical.commons" />
    </jxb:schemaBindings>

    <jxb:bindings node="/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType[@name='tPessoa']">
        <ci:code>
            public static TPessoa fromValue(String v) {
            if(("F".equalsIgnoreCase(v)) || ("PF".equalsIgnoreCase(v))) return PF;
            if(("J".equalsIgnoreCase(v)) || ("PJ".equalsIgnoreCase(v))) return PJ;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
            }
        </ci:code>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

And I am passing inside the maven plugin the argument                       -Xinject-code-extension

But the result observed does not changes.
I read some articles here in StackOverflow but it is unclear to me if this is a limitation of JAXB or if I am missing something.

My idea is to generate a class just like below

```
@XmlType(name = "tPessoa")
@XmlEnum
public enum TPessoa {

    @XmlEnumValue("pf")
    PF("pf"),
    @XmlEnumValue("pj")
    PJ("pj");
    private final String value;

    TPessoa(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static TPessoa fromValue(String v) {
        if(("F".equalsIgnoreCase(v)) || ("PF".equalsIgnoreCase(v))) return PF;
        if(("J".equalsIgnoreCase(v)) || ("PJ".equalsIgnoreCase(v))) return PJ;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```

Because F and PF are synonyms and some underlying systems returns different values for the same entity, some of them returns F others PF and the same behavior for J and PJ.

How to do it? Is it Possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have never managed to inject code into enumerations in JAXB. I could only inject code into complexTypes.

Below you can find an alternative example which injects the `fromValue` method from your question into a complex type and might be useful as well.

### Maven

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.fernandes</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                    <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/xjb</bindingDirectory>
                    <generatePackage>com.fernandes.jaxb</generatePackage>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xinject-code</arg>
                    </args>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>1.11.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="http://xmlns.tui.com/int/customer360/cdm/customer/v1"
            targetNamespace="http://xmlns.tui.com/int/customer360/cdm/customer/v1"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xsd:complexType name="pessoaType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="type" type="tPessoa"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="tPessoa">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Enumeracao que descreve se e uma pessoa fisica ou
                juridica
                Valores possiveis:
                - pf: para PESSOA FiSICA;
                - pj: para PESSOA
                JURiDICA.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="pf"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="pj"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

### Binding file

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              xmlns:ci="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector">
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/schema.xsd">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:simple/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>
    <jxb:bindings node="/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType[@name='pessoaType']">
        <ci:code>
            <![CDATA[
    public static TPessoa fromValue(String v) {
        if(("F".equalsIgnoreCase(v)) || ("PF".equalsIgnoreCase(v))) return TPessoa.PF;
        if(("J".equalsIgnoreCase(v)) || ("PJ".equalsIgnoreCase(v))) return TPessoa.PJ;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }
                ]]>
        </ci:code>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

If you run maven with:

> mvn clean package

You will generate the `TPessoa` class and a `PessoaType`. The latter will contain the static method you specified.

### PessoaType

```
package com.fernandes.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for pessoaType complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="pessoaType"&gt;
 *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;
 *       &lt;sequence&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="type" type="{http://xmlns.tui.com/int/customer360/cdm/customer/v1}tPessoa"/&gt;
 *       &lt;/sequence&gt;
 *     &lt;/restriction&gt;
 *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
 * &lt;/complexType&gt;
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "pessoaType", propOrder = {
    "type"
})
public class PessoaType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
    protected TPessoa type;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the type property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link TPessoa }
     *     
     */
    public TPessoa getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the type property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link TPessoa }
     *     
     */
    public void setType(TPessoa value) {
        this.type = value;
    }


    public static TPessoa fromValue(String v) {
        if(("F".equalsIgnoreCase(v)) || ("PF".equalsIgnoreCase(v))) return TPessoa.PF;
        if(("J".equalsIgnoreCase(v)) || ("PJ".equalsIgnoreCase(v))) return TPessoa.PJ;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    } 
}
```

This is not 100% what you want, but it is pretty close.